# Count 2 columns for occurrence in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I want to count the occurrence of values in column "b" based on column "a" value. I am not sure how to do this in excel.

E.g.

```
 A  |  B  | C
abc | 123 | True
abc | 321 | False
abc | 123 | True
xyz | 987 | True
xyz | 987 | True
qwe | 567 | False
qwe | 765 | False
```

basically I am trying to see if column b value is repeated for each array of values in column a.

Comment: I did not really understand what you want to achieve. Can you show us an example?

Answer (score 1):

So, D2 counts how many and E2 shows true / false as per your column C.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use array formulas for these sort of things.

`=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF($A$2:$A$8=A2,IF($B$2:$B$8=B2,1))))`

[image: counting unique values in sheets]

Comment: What is this `ARRAYFORMULA` function?

Comment: An `ARRAYFORMULA` works over multiple columns or rows. For example, if you select `=ARRAYFORMULA(A1:B5)` you should expect the output to take up 5 rows and 2 columns. However, you can use an aggregate formula such as sum to summarize the response to one cell.

Comment: (I used google sheets to get my current output. In excel, you enter in the formula `=SUM(IF($A$2:$A$8=A2,IF($B$2:$B$8=B2,1)))}` then hit control + shift + enter as an equivalent.